# HOw to get matched string in many strings from database?

Tags: android

[firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywr3L.png)

hi friends, iam beginner, i was trying to create codes that take a string from edit text then match with string in firebase, but i ran into bit trouble that i get "Not Matched in OUr Database", i think iam wrong somewhere, help

```
private void muamalaVerification() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View alertTextMuamala = inflater.inflate(R.layout.muamala_dialog, null);
    final EditText movieMuamala = alertTextMuamala.findViewById(R.id.movie_muamala);

    Muamala = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Miamala/");


    final String MovieMuamala = movieMuamala.getText().toString().trim();
    Muamala.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            String pass = snapshot.getRef().toString();

            if (MovieMuamala.equals(pass)) {
                Toast.makeText(MovieDetails.this, "Excellent Matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Save to database in UsedMiamala child
                DatabaseReference MuamalaToUsed = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsedMiamla");
                MuamalaToUsed.push().setValue(movieMuamala.getText().toString());

                TextView subText = findViewById(R.id.sub_txt);
                subText.setText(movieMuamala.getText().toString());

                Toast.makeText(MovieDetails.this, "Mumamala Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            if (!MovieMuamala.equals(pass)) {
                Toast.makeText(MovieDetails.this, "Not Matched in Our Database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

I only get Not Matched even i write a correct string, i want to match one of those srtings, check the image plse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check `java` code

```
public void verifyWithFirebase(View view) {
        DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Miamala");

        final String MovieMuamala = movieMuamala.getText().toString().trim();

        mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot eachChild: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String value = eachChild.getValue(String.class);

                    Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: " + value);
                    
                    if (MovieMuamala.equals(value))
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, "Excellent Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through all the child nodes to check for a match. Here's a solution but it's in `kotlin` though

```
fun verifyWithFirebase(view: View?) {

        val mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("Miamala")

        val MovieMuamala = editText!!.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }

        query.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) { 
                for (eachChild in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val value = eachChild.getValue(String::class.java)
                        if (MovieMuamala == value)
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Excellent Matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "some eroror $p0")
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: than you but i dont know kotlin, any other i dea?

Comment: please check new answer